# $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ as a ''classical'' topological space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, soft-question, schemes, visualization

I've read recently the definition of the *prime spectrum* associated to a ring and how it can be made into a topological space.

I've read that $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ is really important and that it can be represented by the ***[Mumford's treasure map](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/mumfords-treasure-map)***.

But, can be this topological space seen as a usual set ($\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ for example) with a particular topology?

Comment: Recall: $\mathrm{Spec} \Bbb Z [x]$ is not Hausdorff, thus it is not a subspace of any Hausdorff space.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you mean by "represented". But to write in more words what @Crostul is saying: $\text{Spec}\mathbb Z[x]$ is not homeomorphic to  $\mathbb R$, nor to $\mathbb C$, nor to any other [Hausdorff space](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/general-topology/t2-space-or-hausdorff-space.html), nor to any subspace of a Hausdorff space, because a subspace of a Hausdorff space must be Hausdorff, and a space homeomorphic to a Hausdorff space must be Hausdorff.

Comment: What are you asking? $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ is a topological space: this means it's a set equipped with topology. I don't know what you mean by a "usual set"... The set of prime ideals in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a perfectly good set. Of course, $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ is countably infinite, so it's in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, and hence it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with some topology. But this topology won't be very natural, and you won't gain anything by thinking about this homeomorphism.

Comment: With "representation" I mean to give a set and a family of subsets that allow me to visualize it in a real-world way. Actually the original definition of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[x]$ don't allow me to imagine it @LeeMosher

Comment: I was thinking in something similar to the comment of @AlexKruckman

Comment: General topological spaces, and especially the non-Hausdorff ones ubiquitous in algebraic geometry, are hard to visualize in a "real-world way". The sketch in Mumford's Red Book that you refer to in the question is a serious attempt to help you visualize this space and come up with some kind of geometric intuition. You're not going to get a much more helpful representation than that.

Comment: At first I'd say it is easier to look at $Spec(K[x])$. Let $U$ be a subset of $L = K_{algebraic-closure}$ and $I(U) = \{ f \in  K[x], \forall u \in U, f(u) = 0\}$ and $V(J) = \{ u \in L, \forall f \in J, f(u)=0\}$ then the topology is such that $V(I(U)) = \overline{U}$ is the smallest closed set containing $U$. Then identifying $u \in L$ with its minimal polynomial $h \in K[x]$, so $(h)$ is a prime ideal of $K[x]$, we can do the same replacing $L$ by $Spec(K[x])$ the set of prime ideals of $K[x]$ and $f(u)=0$ by $f \equiv 0 \bmod (h)$, and generalize to $Spec(R)$ for any ring.

Comment: Your answer make me sad @AlexKruckman, since it's hard to me to get a "geometrical" intuition from it. But thanks for your time, tell me if you think that this answer must be deleted since it's not so useful.

Comment: I do not think it should be deleted, because through your question I learned about Mumford's treasure map, and others may also. I do feel there is perhaps a better question to be asked, though. One might ask a detailed question about how to understand Mumford's treasure map, assuming that one has put some time into trying to understand the map.

Comment: @LeeMosher actually there is a superb blog that explain in detail the Mumford's sketch. this is why I've not asked it. Here the link where I've learnt all I know about this scheme: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/mumfords-treasure-map

Comment: I think that whenever you want to think geometrically about a scheme it is a good idea to think about the set of $R$-valued points for some ring $R$, which in the case $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[X]$ is just $\mathbb Z$ (for $R=\mathbb Z$). Of course this is just a set and not equipped with any topology.